Can I fly within the US on an expired ESTA?
Background. I'm flying from the UK to the US. So if I fly to the US while my ESTA is valid it is fine. But can I fly from one US state to another if the ESTA has expired?
For example if I flew into Chicago on the 1st of the month, my ESTA expired on the 5th and I wanted to fly from Chicago, Illinois to Orlando, Florida on the 10th of the month, could I still do that? Or would I be stopped? I know I could fly back to the UK if it was expired.
Simple timeline:
1st: Entry
5th: ESTA expires
10th: Domestic interstate travel

An ESTA is not required for domestic travel, and does not need to be valid for the full duration of your stay. As long as you're abiding by the terms of the VWP (that is, you're staying in the US/Canada/Mexico for no more than 90 days) there's no issue.
You will show your passport when checking in, when going through the security check, and/or when boarding the plane, but that's just to verify identity; they won't be checking for immigration permissions.

There are some exceptions here. For example, most non-US nationals would need an active ESTA to travel to the USVI, CNMI, or Guam from elsewhere in the US or to travel to the 50 states, DC, or Puerto Rico from the USVI, CNMI, Guam, or American Samoa. (Traveling to American Samoa requires an OK Board, not ESTA.)
